# doctrine event onflush

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

the class Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs have method getEntity() for see get Entity->getId(); what object id was modified.

I use the method public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs) . How can see the ID of the object that has been inserted?

```
 foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() AS $entity) {
        if (!$entity instanceof Modificacion) {
        $modificacion = new Modificacion();
        $modificacion->setFechamod(new \DateTime('now'));          
        $className = join('', array_slice(explode('\\', get_class($entity)), -1));
        $modificacion->setEntidad($className);         
        $modificacion->setIdentificador($eventArgs->getEntity()->getId());//not working
        $modificacion->setTipo('Inserción');
        $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
        $modificacion->setEmpleado($securityContext->getToken()->getUser());
        $modificacion->setInfo('');
        $em->persist($modificacion);
        $classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($modificacion));
        $uow->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $modificacion);
                        }
                    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: But you can use the event postPersist for an object that has been inserted.

Comment: do yourself a favor and program with English terms and variable names.